# I have lost both gmail id and password, how can I recover it

Tags: gmail

I have forgotten both my email id and password, only the mobile number is with me. Please help me to find out it.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover your Gmail with your phone number or recovery mail using [this link.](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/usernamerecovery)